# Javascript function not getting called at the onclick event of a button

Tags: javascript

Not sure why the open function is not getting called at the onclick even of the button.
Any help will be highly useful

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function open(){
alert('gsfhdgf');
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("fade").style.display="block";
}

</script>
<div id="fade" style="display:none">

<div id="overlay" style="display:none">
this is my content
</div>
</div>
<button  onclick="open()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @1nflktd What would that change?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup I'm not saying its the problem here, im just saying its *good* practice to put it there, but put it anywhere if you want to

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`open` is already used as a function name (`window.open`, `document.open`...)

Name your function something else (preferably something *meaningful*) and it will work.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol : thanks mate.it didn't cross my mind ;).it.working fine now